# Why is my waypoint added class not removing when scrolling down

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, toggle, jquery-waypoints

I am running into a situation in which I have a box that comes in `#projMarker`, which is initially set as `display: none`. When it reaches `#subSolSec` it changes to `display:block`. I am doing this with jQuery's Waypoints function.

This aspect of it works well, but what I don't understand is when I exit `#subSolSec`, the `projMarker` does not go back to `display: none` it does this when exiting the waypoint when scrolling up, but not when exiting downwards.

To add/remove the class, I am using `toggleClass`.

Does anyone see what I am doing wrong?

```js
$('#subSolSec').waypoint(function() {
  $('#projMarker').toggleClass('active');
}, {
  offset: '0'
});
```

```css
.area {
  width: 100%;
  height: 750px;
}
#sec1 {
  background: blue;
}
#sec3 {
  background: red;
}
#projMarker {
 position: fixed;
 top: 30%;
 right: 10px;
 width: 150px;
 height: auto;
 border: 1px solid black;
 z-index: 2;
 display: none;
}
#projMarker.active {
 display: block;
}
.markerItem {
 display: block;
 margin-bottom: 15px;
 color: #4D4D4D;
 font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
 letter-spacing: .1rem;
 font-size: .8rem;
 line-height: 1.5em;
}

#subSolSec {
 width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
.secSlant {
 height: auto;
}
.slantTop {
 background: #FFF;
 z-index: 1;
 position: relative;
}
.slantTop:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    background: inherit;
    position: absolute;
    top: -6px;
    height: 500px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-transform: skewY(10.5deg);
    -moz-transform: skewY(10.5deg);
    -ms-transform: skewY(10.5deg);
    -o-transform: skewY(10.5deg);
    transform: skewY(10.5deg);
    -webkit-transform-origin: 100%;
    -moz-transform-origin: 100%;
    -ms-transform-origin: 100%;
    -o-transform-origin: 100%;
    transform-origin: 100%;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 -8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 -12px 28px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 -8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 -12px 28px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
    box-shadow: 0 -8px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05), 0 -12px 28px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.05);
}
.slantTop-noshadow:before {
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
.slantContainer {
 padding: 20px 0;
 margin: 0 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/waypoints/4.0.1/jquery.waypoints.min.js"></script>
<section class="area" id="sec1">

</section>
<section id="subSolSec">
  <div id="projMarker">
    <div class="markerItem">
      Section 1
    </div>
    <div class="markerItem">
      Section 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secSlant" id="secSlant1">
    <div class="slantTop">
      <div class="slantContainer">
        <div class="slantBlock1">
          <h2 class="hG2 slantTitle">1</h2>
          <p class="slantDesc">
            Area for 1
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="secSlant" id="secSlant2">
    <div class="slantTop">
      <div class="slantContainer">
        <div class="slantBlock1">
          <h2 class="hG2 slantTitle">2</h2>
          <p class="slantDesc">
            Area for 2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
<section class="area" id="sec3">

</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add another waypoint to disengage the waypoint the way you want. So:

```
$('#sec3').waypoint(function() {
  $('#projMarker').toggleClass('active');
}, {
  offset: '0'
});
```

Comment: hmm i just tried it in your code updated and it seemed to work. Add it to this current code, update it and run it here and see if it works for you